# Astro Property 'color' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props'

Tags: javascript, astrojs

I have the following component **Button.astro**

```
---
interface Props {
    text: string;
    style: string;
    color: string;
}

const { 
    text, 
    style = "min-w-[70px] p-2 rounded-md m-2 hover:bg-black hover:text-white",
    color 
} = Astro.props;

const css = `${style} ${color}`
---

<button class={css}>{text}</button>
```

and this is how i use it

```
---
import Layout from '../Layouts/Layout.astro';
import Button from '../components/Button.astro';
const base_url = import.meta.env.VITE_BASE_URL;
---
<Layout title="Home Page">
    <Button text="Add" color="bg-red-500"></Button>
    <a href=`${base_url}/about`>Go About</a>
</Layout>
```

Everything works fine, however i see this error message in my code editor VSCode

> Type '{ text: string; color: string; }' is not assignable to type
> 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props'.   Property 'color' does not exist on
> type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props'.ts(2322)

Am using astro with vanilla javascript, can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code and how to solve this problem